# Monitoring Microphone recording level simple?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, winapi, winmm

I need a VERY simple way to monitor and adjust the line input level.  I want to be able to adjust this before I do a recording, then record.

All I am looking for is a progressbar and a slider.  The slider could adjust the recording level to prevent clipping.

I have searched for weeks, and everything I find is in C++.  I am using vs 2010, vb.net on a windows 7 machine.

I tried using winMM.dll, but I get lost easily with it. I tried in vain to use NAudio, but I can't adapt his Silverlight code to my project.

I can use the recording level dialog in the little speaker icon in the system tray, but what a hassle doing that for every recording...

Comment: Use BASS.NET library.

Comment: I don't understand.. are you asking for something already all done, or a pointer on how to achieve this yourself ? And when you talk about the input level, do you mean the microphone volume level itself ? Or the live ambient noise level captured by the microphone ? The answer will be really different then.